# Conversion from Iphone Core Surface RGB Frame into ffmepg AVFarme

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert Core Surface RGB frame buffer(Iphone) to ffmpeg Avfarme to encode into a movie file. But I am not getting the correct video output (video showing colors dazzling not the correct picture)

I guess there is something wrong with converting from core surface frame buffer into AVFrame.

Here is my code :

```
Surface *surface = [[Surface alloc]initWithCoreSurfaceBuffer:coreSurfaceBuffer];
[surface lock];
unsigned int height = surface.height;
unsigned int width = surface.width;
unsigned int alignmentedBytesPerRow = (width * 4);
if (!readblePixels) {
    readblePixels = CGBitmapAllocateData(alignmentedBytesPerRow * height);
    NSLog(@"alloced readablepixels");
}
unsigned int bytesPerRow = surface.bytesPerRow;
void *pixels = surface.baseAddress;
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    memcpy(readblePixels + alignmentedBytesPerRow * j, pixels + bytesPerRow * j, bytesPerRow);
}

pFrameRGB->data[0] = readblePixels; // I guess here is what I am doing wrong.
pFrameRGB->data[1] = NULL;
pFrameRGB->data[2] = NULL;
pFrameRGB->data[3] = NULL;

pFrameRGB->linesize[0] = pCodecCtx->width;
pFrameRGB->linesize[1] = 0;
pFrameRGB->linesize[2] = 0;
pFrameRGB->linesize[3] = 0;


sws_scale (img_convert_ctx, pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize,
       0, pCodecCtx->height,
       pFrameYUV->data, pFrameYUV->linesize);
```

Please help me out.

Thanks,

Raghu

Comment: You know `Surface` is a private API and that this app will never be accepted on the store because of that?

Comment: If I am not wrong, All people are using core surface using dynamic calls with dlopen() and dlsym() and apples seems to be accepting those guys apps.

Answer (score 3):

This will solve the problem:

```
pFrameRGB->linesize[0] = pCodecCtx->width * 4; // linesize includes total bytes for the line (ARGB)
```

Dont waste time though, you are not supposed to use Surface as St3fan suggested. App will be rejected.

Comment: I think there are evidences that people using core surface using dlopen() and dlsym() to hide from apple static api catcher

Comment: Yes I solved the problem using width*4 and also had to change RGB24 to RGB32. Now it is working fine

Comment: Do you know any valid way to get the raw stream from camera ?

Comment: No, I dont know of any valid way. Update us of any advancements.